# How to configure a Kafka topic for use as snapshot store

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

This topic should hold only the latest 'document X updated' event for each X. But I cannot get the topic configured correctly and it retains multiple copies.

My idea is to keep segments small, as well as all related timeouts, flush and retention times.

The topic settings (I do not have a clear enough understanding of where and with what prefix each of the options is applied, so there are probably several unused and unrelated ones as well as exaggerated numbers - corrections welcome):

```
"cleanup.policy"                    -> "compact",
"file.delete.delay.ms"              -> "10",
"segment.bytes"                     -> "10000",
"delete.retention.ms"               -> "10",
"retention.bytes"                   -> "10000",
"segment.ms"                        -> "10",
"retention.ms"                      -> "10",
"min.cleanable.dirty.ratio"         -> "0.001",
"flush.messages"                    -> "1",
"flush.ms"                          -> "10",
"min.compaction.lag.ms"             -> "1",
"log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms" -> "1"
```

I feed the topic with [akka-streams-kafka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/home.html):

```
val ids = List("12345", ...)

val publish: Future[Done] = Source(ids ++ ids ++ ids ++ ids ++ ids)
  .map { id =>
    ProducerMessage.Message(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, id, id), id)
  }
  .via(producerFlow)
  .map(logResult)
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
Await.result(publish, 3.seconds)
```

after waiting for several seconds, I count the messages:

```
var count = 0
val runCount = Consumer
  .plainSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topic))
  .map { t =>
    count += 1
    t
  }
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
Try { Await.result(runCount, timeout) }
```

I expect the consumer to receive `ids.length` messages, but it always receives all the produced messages on the first run and even more on subsequent runs.

Some compaction does take place - if I run the test several times, the count of consumed messages stops growing and I see the segment deletions in the kafka log - but there are still multiple messages for each key.

How do I use a kafka topic as a snapshot store?

Using kafka 0.10.2.1

Thank you.

Comment: I would require a few details to investigate: 1. could you please provide the broker log, 2. Configurations at broker level would help.

Comment: @SudheshRajan sure, here are the [lines from the broker.log during repeated test exec](https://gist.github.com/ksilin/095353de745ce8707d6150eae6796c18) and here is the [server.properties](https://gist.github.com/ksilin/415964ec885d5e7c695986046c04c65b). `server.properties` is vanilla. Any more info I can provide?

Answer (score 2):

According to Kafka specs: "Log compaction ensures that Kafka will always retain ***at least*** the last known value for each message key within the log of data for a single topic partition". I.e. Kafka doesn't guarantees to keep exactly one message per key, however it guarantees to always have latest message version for each key.

Comment: Log Compaction seems to be the way to go

Comment: It's the most current segment of each topic partition that remains open for writes and is not compacted (until it rolls over and a new segment file become the write active segment). Otherwise all other segments should only have one message per key after compaction periodically finishes running.

Answer (score 0):

You can try working around with the configuration to see if what you want can be achieved (Refer [this](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs)), but I would suggest to handle it at application level, using only the latest message with that key as the valid message, since log compaction runs on a separate thread and there is no way to trigger it to happen after every updation (and even if there was a way, it would not be very efficient).